# Flutter: Alinhamento Row

Tags: flutter, dart

Boa tarde pessoal!

Estou começando agora aprender a mexer com `flutter`, e estou com dúvidas em questão ao alinhamento das palavras de baixo dos cards Suspeitos e Investigados.

Eu gostaria de deixá-los centralizados assim como está a palavra **Suspeito** no centro do card. Queria fazer o mesmo para a palavra **Investigados**.
retornando em um GridView

Qual seria o método correto? Segue meu código:

```
Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
        width: 400,
        height: 30,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Suspeitos',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            Text('Investigados',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
          ],
        );
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi, você quer que a linha com os títulos 'Suspeitos' e 'Investigados' sejam alinhadas de acordo com os seus respectivos cards. Para isso você pode envolver a criação dos cards em uma `Column` que irá conter o card + título.

Como é melhor de entender na prática, seria algo como o código abaixo:

```dart
  Widget _buildBody() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: <Widget>[
        _buildCardText('Suspeitos'),
        _buildCardText('Investigados'),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCardText(String title) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 100,
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  '0',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            Text(
              title,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 16,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Basicamente você possui uma `Row` que tem duas `Column`, onde cada uma contém um card + o título.

Você vai controlar o alinhamento do título de acordo com o `crossAxisAlignment` da `Column`, que por padrão alinha ao centro mesmo.

Resultado:

[image: Resultado]

Teste online com o [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/233f9f86cb7dd9cfde26802a6369f7c4).

Comment: Cara muito bom obrigado, porem o jeito que você me ensinou, ele cria um do lado do outro se eu passar mais parâmetros na função por exemplo  _buildCardText('Suspeitos'), _buildCardText('Investigados'),  ele cria um do lado do outro ai se eu passar denovo por exemplo 3 vezes buildCardText('Suspeitos'), _buildCardText('Investigados'), _buildCardText('Confirmado'), ele continua empilhando um do lado do outro e eu precisava que ele os cards ficasse um do lado do outro passou mais paramentos ele vai criando em baixo em uma nova row

Comment: seria no caso retornar em uma gridview nesse codigo

Comment: Mas não é isso que a sua pergunta original estava pedindo, você não tinha citado que haviam mais cards. Bom, nesse caso basta usar o próprio widget GridView https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html

Comment: Consegui amigo obrigado segui o link e um vídeo no youtube sobre as Gridview obrigadooo

Comment: @Victor se lhe ajudou, poderia marcar a resposta como aceita. ;)